# Spring JPA save not always executed on DB

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using a Spring JPA repository to work on some data over a database.

```
public List<DHData> editDHData(int id, DHData dhData){
    DHEntity e = dhRepository.findById(id).get();
    int val = e.findDHData(dhData.getDec1(),dhData.getDec2());
    if(val >= 0) {
        e.getDHData().get(val).setEval(dhData.getEval());
        System.out.println(val);
        dhRepository.save(e);
    }
    return e.getDHData();
}
```

Basically I'm getting the whole entity, changing what i need to change, and then i save it using JPA.
Apparently, when i receive very fast requests on the same entity (we're using an Angular frontend that sends this type of request one after another with no timeout), it seems like it's not able to processing and over the database i get saved only the **last** request.

Is there a way to make every call consistent and so that they're executed one after another and not skipped?

**Example**

My DHEntity contains (together with other info) the following data, that i'm accessing and modifying with editDHData method.

```
{ "dec1": 1, 
 "dec2": 2, 
 "eval": 0},
{ "dec1": 1, 
 "dec2": 3, 
 "eval": 0},
{ "dec1": 2, 
 "dec2": 3, 
 "eval": 0}
```

The method i posted above, is executed three times to change the values

First call:

```
{ "dec1": 1, 
 "dec2": 2, 
 "eval": 0.5}
```

Second call:

```
{ "dec1": 1, 
 "dec2": 3, 
 "eval": 1}
```

Third call:

```
{ "dec1": 2, 
 "dec2": 3, 
 "eval": 8}
```

After every call, i save the entity. Only the last call is kept, therefore this is what i get in the end:

```
    { "dec1": 1, 
     "dec2": 2, 
     "eval": 0},
    { "dec1": 1, 
     "dec2": 3, 
     "eval": 0},
    { "dec1": 2, 
     "dec2": 3, 
     "eval": 8}
```

Apparently the methods are called 3 times but only the last one is saved into the database.
**Is there something i can do over the entity/repository to make sure it works and it's consistent?**
The database is PostgreSQL, and the frontend is Angular (but i doubt it's relevant). When i do the calls over Postman (of course taking more time to do them) it works fine.

In addition, i thought that maybe it's because the method is not "thread-safe". If every call is executed by a different thread, i think that it first reads the entity as not modified, and then when it saves it's overwriting. I would need all of the operations to be sequential and to ensure persistency of the database (which is not happening)

Comment: can you post your Entity class here?

Comment: @Shoshi yes, here it is:
https://pastebin.com/raw/XEVcENZq
I omitted methods and constructors to have it shorter

Comment: are you 100% sure that in these three calls every time the condition of `if` is satisfied?

Comment: yes, that one is just to retrieve the id of the array (and check that it's positive and existing). As i said, the calls are working perfectly every time if done separately. When done in a rapid succession they have problems. I believe it's a transaction problem or something. I just don't know how to fix it

Comment: try using `dhRepository.saveAndFlush()`

Comment: like @Shoshi , I also think your problem inside the if condition. You should add `val--`   inside of if

Comment: @Mastarius: try to use `dhRepository.saveAndFlush()` instead of `dhRepository.save()`. let me know what happen?

Comment: @Shoshi it doesn't change the results. I tried it just now

Comment: also, annotate your `editDHData` method with `@Transactional`

Comment: @Shoshi I did, and i used Isolation.SERIALIZABLE because i have to avoid dirty reads problems. But then i get a PGSQL exception:

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not serialize access due to concurrent update

Comment: read this: https://dzone.com/articles/concurrency-and-locking-with-jpa-everything-you-ne
 you need `Pessimistic Lock`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, your back-end Spring application is multi-threaded, and uses a thread per request, so your requests are not necessarily happening sequentially.

As @Shoshi pointed out, you would need pessimistic locking on your database updates to make sure that the updates are done in the order that they are received, and that each update completes before the next one is executed.

However, I would also take a harder look at the front-end. The fact that your front end is sending a flurry of update requests for the same data sounds odd to me. It might be better to aggregate the changes on the front-end, and then send one update request to the back-end.

Comment: Since i've been troubleshooting this for the whole evening, i came to the same conclusion:

First i tried to put transactional isolation to serializable, and to use Spring Retry to retry the call several times (else i just get the exception but nothing changes as for the results). Then i decided to aggregate all the changes and to send a single request (so that i avoid this kind of mess). It bugs me that i wasn't able to solve by setting the transactions correctly, but in the end it wasn't worth any more headache